# How come Logs-Odds Scoring Matrix is symmetric?

Tags: bioinformatics

I am studying Pevsner's Bioinformatics.

It is stated that Logs-Odds Scoring Matrix is symmetric at page 89.

But with given the equation to calculate the cells of the matrix, I find different scores for from cysteine to leucine and for from leucine to cysteine.

How is this possible?
Do we take the lowest value?

The equation used for constructing Logs-Odds Matrix from a corresponding Pam matrix is : $s_{ij}=10\times\log_{10}(M_{ij}/f_i)$

where $M_{ij}$ is the observed frequency of substitution for each pair aminoacids.
and $f_i$ is the probability of aminoacid residue i occurring in the second sequence by chance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics, not the underlying biology. Please ask at [stats.se].

Comment: To answer this will require more information, given that most respondents will not have p. 89 handy. What is the equation you speak of?

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not know what calculations you did. I am going to answer your
"How come Logs-Odds Scoring Matrix is symmetric?".
Let us assume that it is not.
So
\begin{equation}
S_{ij} \neq S_{ji}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
M_{ij}*f_j \neq M_{ji}*f_i
\end{equation}
Is this not in contradiction with Bayes theorem?. Yes.
So log odds matrix is symmetric.